# Defining assignment function as variable in tensroflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am training a neural network by SGD (batch size = 1). The inputs are randomly generated, and the labels are calculated based on the input. AKA the data does not have to be realistic, but the relationships between inputs and labels are specific. I will train my NN only 1 epoch, but with many batches.

I have the following code:

```
training_input = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(...))
assign_training_input_with_random_values = training_input.assign(tf.random_normal(...))

//Create a session, initialize a bunch of variables, construct a neural network...
for batch in range(batch_number):
    sess.run(assign_training_input_with_random_values)
    //Train my neural network...
```

However I noticed that if I write the above code differently the speed goes down by a lot:

```
//Run the assignment operation directly without defining it as a variable
for batch in range(batch_size)
    sess.run(training_input.assign(tf.random_normal(...)))
    //Train my neural network...
```

The first snippet being significantly faster makes me worry that tensorflow is only randomizing when I define the assign_training_input_with_random_values variable, and the same training examples are fed to the NN over every batch afterwards. In this case, the NN will probably not generalize well. Meanwhile, the second snippet is slow because it is randomizing every batch. Is this actually the case or is there another reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

First the explanation to your observations

### Computational difference between 1st and 2nd solutions

It makes sense that your first solution is faster than the second. You define the assign operation once and then execute that for 100 epochs. However in the 2nd solution you create an op every epoch, growing the computational graph over time which causes your program to slow down.

### Observation about the 1st solution

(After @Y.Z.'s finding) Apparently the first solution does evaluate to different random number arrays every time you run it. Therefore, the first solution is also valid.

### Another way to implement this

The correct way to implement your solution would be to use a `tf.placeholder` to feed values in every epoch the following way.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

training_input = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[3, 2]))
tf_random = tf.placeholder(shape=[3, 2], dtype=tf.float32)
assign_training_input_with_random_values = training_input.assign(tf_random)

#Create a session, initialize a bunch of variables, construct a neural network...
epoch=0
with tf.Session() as sess:
  while epoch < 10:
      epoch+= 1
      sess.run(assign_training_input_with_random_values, feed_dict={tf_random:np.random.normal(size=(3,2))})
```

### Comparing Solution 1 vs My solution

So turns out, both your first solution and my solution will not grow the graph. If you run the line

`print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])`

for your first solution and my solution (Be careful to run `tf.reset_default_graph()` at the beginning) you'll see that the number of tensors remain constant regardless of the number of iterations. Appears that TensorFlow is smart enough to prune those old `tf.random` tensors no longer used.

Comment: I actually ran a simpler code snippet in response to my original question: X = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape = [2,3]),dtype=tf.float32)     Y = tf.assign(x, tf.random.normal([3,5])       with tf.Session() as sess:    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())                 for i in range(10):  sess.run(y)    print(x.eval())    and it gave me a different x every time.

Comment: However I did also try the placeholder method you suggested, and it also gave me different x every time.

Comment: That is quite interesting. I got the same result. I think I was wrong about my comment about first solution always evaluating to the same random number array.

Comment: @Y.Z. Updated my answer.